# AppleScript how to find pattern and set it to a record or list?

Tags: list, find, applescript, record, bbedit

In AppleScript I know how to do a typical find with something like:

```
tell application "BBEdit"
    activate
    open find window
    find "memberFunction\\(\\)" searching in text 1 of text document "theFile" options {search mode:grep, wrap around:true} with selecting match
end tell
```

and I can do a multi file search find:

```
tell application "BBEdit"
    activate
    find "memberFunction\\(\\)" searching in {file "path:to:project.bbprojectd:"} options {search mode:grep, showing results:true}
end tell
```

but I'd like to return the find multi result and save it to a file so I thought I'd need to save it to a record or list then repeat through the input but when I try:

```
tell application "BBEdit"
    activate
    set findFunction to {}
    set findFunction to {find "memberFunction\\(\\)" searching in {file "path:to:project.bbprojectd:"} options {search mode:grep, showing results:true}} as list
end tell
```

or:

```
set findFunction to {find "memberFunction\\(\\)" searching in {file "path:to:project.bbprojectd:"} options {search mode:grep, showing results:true}} as record
```

I get an error of:

> No result was returned from some part of this expression.

Why is the find not being set to the record or list?  Is there a way I can set what the multi-file search does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is that you put the `find` command in a list.

---

> To get a record from the find command:
>
> The `showing results` property must be **false** and the `returning
>   results` property must be **true**, otherwise the **findFunction**
>   variable will be undefined

Here's the script:

```
tell application "BBEdit"
    set findFunction to find "memberFunction\\(\\)" searching in file "path:to:project.bbprojectd:" options {search mode:grep, showing results:false, returning results:true}
end tell
```