# How to turn an AppleScript list into a string

Tags: list, applescript, record, repeat, bbedit

Trying to learn how to use AppleScript records and lists to their upmost potential I've been trying to create a report of a BBEdit project but I'm finding very limited documentation.  I asked a question [yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43550034/applescript-how-to-find-pattern-and-set-it-to-a-record-or-list) trying to figure out why my find pattern wasn't working but after finding out that the issue was from me lacking `returning results:true` I was able to get the result record and I verified it was a record after reading [Class](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_classes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH1g-BBCFEDGB) and running:

```
class of findFunction
```

Since it says it's a record I reviewed [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_classes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH1g-BBCDGEAH) and ran `length of findFunction` and `count of findFunction` and they both returned 2.  I was curious to know what the two items were in the record so I used `return findFunction` and was told there was:

```
found: true
found matches: list of X items
```

Wanting to know where and what files the matches were located in the list, I did some more searching and read [Lists and records](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/AppleScript_Programming/Lists_and_records) and ran:

```
set theMatches to get found matches of findFunction
```

it returned the list items and checking the new variable with `get count of theMatches` I am able get the quantity of items in the targeted list inside the record.  When I review what's in the list (learned from: [How to get a value from a list with a string in AppleScript?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/164317/how-to-get-a-value-from-a-list-with-a-string-in-applescript) and [Searching for items in list](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/83976/searching-for-items-in-list)) I am able to conclude that when using the `find` in BBEdit every item in the list contains:

```
end_offset : 
match_string :
message :
result_file :
result_kind :
result_line :
start_offset :
```

Experimenting with an item I set a variable with:

```
set itemOne to get item 1 of theMatches
```

and checked to see if it worked with:

```
display dialog (result_file of itemOne) as text
```

and a dialog with the full file path was displayed.  Trying to utilize DRY I created:

```
set filesResult to get (result_file of (get item 1 of theMatches)) as text
```

Wanting to add any of the mentioned above to a file with something like:

```
set filesResult to get (result_file of (get item 1 of theMatches)) as text
set theMessage to get (message of (get item 1 of theMatches)) as text
set combined to filesResult & ":" & theMessage
```

I recalled being able to use the clipboard and found [Set clipboard to Applescript variable?](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=18629) so I added:

```
set filesResult to the clipboard
make new text document
paste
```

but my issue I'm running into is how can I take every item in the list `found_matches` and add it to the clipboard an item on each line?  I thought about using a `repeat` but I get an error when I try:

```
repeat with x from 1 to (length of matchesItems)
    set filesResult to get (result_file of (get item x of theMatches)) as text
    set theMessage to get (message of (get item x of theMatches)) as text
    set combined to filesResult & ":" & theMessage
end repeat
```

With a message of:

> The variable matchesItems is not defined.

So how can I get every item from the list into the clipboard with every item on it's own line so I can paste all items from the clipboard into a new file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To clarify wording

```
theList = {A,B,C} -- this is a list with 3 variables
theRecord = {A:something, B:somethingElse, C:somethingElseTwo} -- this is a record.
```

A list can be addressed by its index.

```
theList's item 1 -- A
```

A record can be addressed by its keys

```
A of theRecord -- something
```

To get all items of a list into a string repeat it by its index (saying every item is of type text)

```
set finalString to ""
repeat with thisItem in TheList
    set finalString to finalString & thisItem & return -- the return creates a new line
end repeat
```

Then you have finalString to do with whatever you like.

To get every item of a record you have to know it's keys (if it's not a ASOC NSDictionary)

```
set finalString to ""
set finalString to finalString & A of theRecord & return;
-- repeat last line with every key
```

Comment: set end of myList to "c"